# How do I search results from jquery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I'm having a bit of a problem investigating the result from my `get` in my script. I got the following code to check if a user is still logged in:

```
$.get("nowhereGet", function(result){
    if($(result).find('[id="loginInput"]'))
    {
        //HTML is in the response then we have been logged out and the user needs to go to 
        window.location.href = "login";
    }
    });
```

Now if the user is logged in Struts will return one html-page in `result` from my get. If the user has been logged out different page will be returned one with and element `id="loginInput"`in it.
I thought the above would do the trick but no love. What am I doing wrong?
Is there a better way to do this than to ping the server with a random `get`? I need a method that performes this check using ajax and any `get` or `post` done while logged out will get intercepted and the result will be the login-page instead of the intended page

Comment: do you have any code, I don't know what means Struts (i'm a spanish speaker), let me know if you have anu example code in order to help you

Comment: @jesper Struts is a MFC for webprogramming. Google Appache Struts for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [other soloution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042843/struts-interceptor-giving-a-stream-result) and with help from Steven Benitez I got it working. Follow the link for more information but in short I let my interceptor do the work instead. If a certain path/action is called the interceptor will return a text stream that I can read from my script.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#result').get(......);` ???

**UPDATE**
so the element #result would have what ever the #loginInput has

`$('#result').load('login.php #loginInput');`

Otherwise look for a json option because the way you are doing it, its kinda messy

Unless you are looking for this

```
$.get("nowhereGet", function(result){
    if(result && $(result).find('#loginInput').length)
    {
        //HTML is in the response then we have been logged out and the user needs to go to 
        window.location.href = "login";
    }
    });
```

Comment: Should it not be `$("#loginInput")` or `.find("#loginInput)`? As Skadlig said result contains html?

Comment: Sorry @Val that didn't work. Firebug says value undefined when I do `get("title")` for instance.

Comment: well it shouldn't coz he needs to fetch a url and return the html to the page, and login should be on server side not javascript, coz anyone can bypass the way he is thinking about it :)

Comment: I believe that the problem is that jquery won't let me search the result as if it was html. But I have found another soloution I'm going to post for completness.