# Struts interceptor giving a stream result

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I got an interceptor that I'm trying to get to output a stream when a certain action is calling. This is part of my code in the inteceptor:

```
InputStream inputStream;    

public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception
{
    if (currAction.contentEquals("actionToTest"))
    {
        String result = "TRUE";
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return "resultToGiveStream";
    }
}
```

`inputStream` has got it's own getters and setters.
And in `struts.xml`:

```
<global-results>
    <result type="stream" name="resultToGiveStream">
        <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
```

But when I call actionToTest I only receive this in my console:

```
2011-maj-18 11:19:16 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
ALLVARLIG: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
```

Is it a lost cause to get it to output what I want? I haven' found anyone doing anything similar.
This code is an atempt for a workaround for [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031359/how-do-i-search-results-from-jquery-get).

Comment: Does your code have to be in the Interceptor or can it be moved into the Action class?  I wonder if Struts is looking for the `inputStream` variable in the action class and can't find it since it's in the Interceptor class?

Comment: @nmc No the return stream didn't have to be in the interceptor (though som variation of `if (currAction.contentEquals("actionToTest"))` had to be there. Moving the inputstream was how I solved it at first but that had the drawback of requiring another get wich I thought looked untidy if not that expensive time wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Struts2 is looking for the `getInputStream()` method on your action and it isn't finding it.

You could try placing the inputStream on the stack manually from within the interceptor. Something like:

```
invocation.getInvocationContext().put("inputStream", inputStream);
```